# Homeomorphism in periodic Sobolev space

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

How can I show that between $H^{s}(T)$, and $l_{s}^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ (the set of sequences $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}(1+\left | k \right |^{2})^{s}\left | \alpha (k) \right |^{2}< \infty $) there is a linear isometric homeomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Define $U : H^s(\mathbb{T})\rightarrow\ell^2_s(\mathbb{Z})$ by
$$
           Uf = \left\{ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx\cdot(1+ik)^{s} \right\}_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}.
$$

Comment: how can I explain the continuity, the continuity of inverse?

Comment: U is bijective? second it is necessary to see that $\left \| U(f),U(g) \right \|_{l_{s}^{2}}=\left \|f,g  \right \|_{L^{2}}$